# Pandas multindex on column after merge

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I created this dataframe:

```
d1 = {'john': [10, 11], 'adam': [20,21]}
d2 = {'john': [1,12], 'adam': [3,34]}
test_df1= pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
test_df2= pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

current = pd.concat([test_df1, test_df2], keys=['test_df1','test_df2'], axis=1)
current
```

[image]

but I need to change order in column multiindex. I need to have something like this

```
data = {('John', 'test_df1'): [10, 11], ('John', 'test_df2'): [1, 12], ('Adam', 'test_df1'): [20, 21], ('Adam','test_df2'): [3,34]}
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('John', 'test_df1'),('John', 'test_df2'),('Adam', 'test_df1'),('Adam', 'test_df2')])
needed = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
needed
```

[image]

Could you help me :) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on the other axis, and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
pd.concat([test_df1, test_df2], keys=['test_df1','test_df2']).unstack(0)
```

Output:

```
      john              adam         
  test_df1 test_df2 test_df1 test_df2
0       10        1       20        3
1       11       12       21       34
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `swaplevel` on the resulting dataframe:

```
current.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      adam              john         
  test_df1 test_df2 test_df1 test_df2
0       20        3       10        1
1       21       34       11       12
```